# RxJava toSingle method cannot be resolved

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

The code is

```
import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers;
import io.reactivex.Observable;
import io.reactivex.Observer;
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers;

public class BasePresenter {

    protected <T> void subscribe(Observable<T> observable, Observer<T> observer) {
        observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .toSingle()
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(observer);
    }
```

The problem was that I couldn't use AndroidSchedulers because Observable was 1.x version. I changed import's and now the problem is that i can't use .toSingle

I am just testing RxJava. so, please don't be angry if it is stupid question.

Comment: You should maybe use `.single()` instead of `.toSignle()`. If you explain what is your goal we can be more helpful.

Comment: I am using *.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())* a lot with 1.x, no problem at all.

Comment: toSingle rename(or replaced) by single().See the Wiki Page in RxJava2.